# Using C# ConcurrentBag<T> with multiple producers and a single consumer

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, concurrency, locking

I have a situation where multiple threads are creating one ICollection object. ConcurrentBag seems to be the best (?) solution, since - 1) each thread will have it's own local queue, and 2) the threads do not need to communicate - they are independent. So far so good, but the truth is I need to return an ISet from this method (after all producers had terminated). Even though the current ConcurrentBag instance **IS** distinct (it is guaranteed due to the logic of the application) , I still need to convert it to an ISet, say, HashSet. In this point there are no more producers. And now comes the real question:

When ConcurrentBag is being iterated, will the calling thread grab a lock for **each** item that is not in the thread's local queue? Or will it grab a lock once per thread? Also, is there a difference in the inner implementation between just iterating the bag - and between calling bag.Distinct() explicitly, lock-wise?

Comment: To answer the second part of your question, iterating the collection and calling `Distinct` both use the same mechanics (that is, the `IEnumerable` implementation), so there shouldn't be any difference lock-wise

Comment: There is no lock as iterating ConcurrentBag is done on copy.

Comment: @shay__ Why not create a local `List<T>` for each producer, and aggregate the results once all producers are done?

Comment: @Mateusz So - each thread will create a snapshot for the calling thread to iterate?

Comment: `Distinct()` calls `GetEnumerator()` on the ConcurrentBag, so you will be in effect iterating twice.

Comment: @Mateusz But the collection is locked to make the copy

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Itzchako You are right - but I'm asking just to learn a little bit more about these new classes :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having a look at the source code of the `ConcurrentBag`: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/sys/system/collections/concurrent/ConcurrentBag.cs,537a65e966c1c38d

Iterating through the bag triggers a call to `FreezeBag`. This method calls `AcquireAllLocks`, which browse the queue of each thread and set a lock:

```
/// <summary>
/// local helper method to acquire all local lists locks
/// </summary>
private void AcquireAllLocks()
{
    Contract.Assert(Monitor.IsEntered(GlobalListsLock));

    bool lockTaken = false;
    ThreadLocalList currentList = m_headList;
    while (currentList != null)
    {
        // Try/Finally bllock to avoid thread aport between acquiring the lock and setting the taken flag
        try
        {
            Monitor.Enter(currentList, ref lockTaken);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (lockTaken)
            {
                currentList.m_lockTaken = true;
                lockTaken = false;
            }
        }
        currentList = currentList.m_nextList;
    }
}
```

It will grab a lock once per thread, not once per item.

Iterating or calling `Distinct` both will call the `GetEnumerator` method, so it doesn't make a difference.